# PiCamera preview resolution

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to build a still photo camera with a raspberry pi camera module and the PiCamera python library. When I specify the full resoultion that the sensor can manage, the live preview is cropped, and I would like to get the live preview to show exactly the same frame that I will be capturing when pressing the button, so I can frame the pictures correctly.

Anyone know how to do that?

```
import time
import picamera
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from sys import exit

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
sequence = 1
event_name = "New Camera"

def capturetime():
    global sequence
    camera.capture('%s - %03d.jpg' % (event_name, sequence))
    print("Snapped!")    
    sequence += 1

with picamera.PiCamera(sensor_mode=0) as camera:
    camera.resolution = (2592, 1944)
    camera.start_preview()
    print("¡Presiona la bubinga!")
    while True:
        input_state = GPIO.input(17)
        if input_state == False:
            capturetime()
```

Comment: You should show us the code you are currently using. We aren't psychic.

Comment: Sorry, already posted

Comment: So, What is your problem with this code ?

Comment: My problem is that the preview does not match the final still image. I suppose is what happens with the image in the following link http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/_images/sensor_area.png. I can see the small portion on the screen, but that is not what I get in the final image